# spark ui shows zero executors

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I am running spark 2.0.1 using below options in

```
        SparkSession.builder().master(master).appName(appName).config(conf).getOrCreate();
            opts.put("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
            opts.put("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom");
            opts.put("spark.driver.maxResultSize","0");
            opts.put("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","200");
            opts.put("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","/opt/astra/spark-warehouse");
            opts.put("spark.scheduler.mode","FAIR");
            opts.put("spark.executor.memory","5g");
            opts.put("spark.executor.cores","2");
            opts.put("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","1g");
            opts.put("spark.parquet.block.size","134217728");
```

Spark master is running in AWS on ec2 instance. In spark master ui I can see memory, cores all. But when running job in Job UI executors as below
[image]

Also while looking at thread dump I see lots of connection related threads awaiting. 
[image]

Can someone please point to me what's happening and where to look. As commented here is spark master's snapshot showing allocated resources.
On logs the system seems waiting for resources providing below link

16/11/08 12:46:37 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

[image]

Comment: What does the UI at port 18080 say? Are there resources allocated to the cluster?

Comment: Yes it does, I will add images for that also.

Comment: Looks to me like you have executors with 13.5GB memory. Some other job occupies 5GB of that and you are asking for about 11GB for your job. This just doesn't add up.

Comment: Bit of explanation, the total memory I have is 67.7 GB with all executors, and I tried to submit a job with just 5gb. I have updated the configuration as while submitting this job I just passed 5 gb only. Infact I submitted just one job to the cluster and that was also waiting.